# Is there any way to make a transaction invalid if it is not confirmed before a certain block?

Tags: transactions, confirmations

It seems like it would be useful to avoid replay attacks if your wallet could specify that a transaction must be confirmed before say the (current+100)th block before broadcasting it

I guess there could be a problem with this scheme if the tx was no longer able to be included into a block after a reorg (esp for dependent txs)

Comment: I don't know of any way to accomplish that.  Can you be more specific as to what kind of "replay attack" you are worried about?

Comment: here is an example http://qntra.net/2016/03/a-miner-problem/

Comment: This is not an attack. This is total misunderstaning how the Bitcoin network works.

Comment: In a scenario of permanent backlog of transactions this scenario will need better strategies however

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't a way to make a transaction that has to be included before a certain block number.

And there's a good reason for this: such a transaction would not be what is known as reorg-safe. Generally, transactions should be able to be included in either side of a block chain fork. If you make a transaction that can only be included before a certain block number, and then a fork occurs that makes a chain that doesn't include it before the designated block number, then that transaction gets reversed and so do all transactions that depend on the base transaction.